# PHP Select List

Tags: php

I have a working select list but want to add another option to it. When passed to the next screen if "Deposit", "Balance" or "Full Cost" have been selected it displays one thing, if "Other" is selected it displays something else. I want to add another option to say "Gift Voucher" but just displays the same page as if "Other" was selected. Seems like such a simple thing to do but can't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

```
                            <select name="paymentType">
                                <?php
                                echo "<option value='-1'";
                                if ($paymentTypeId == -1) {
                                    echo " selected='selected'";
                                }
                                echo ">Please Select</option>";
                                echo "<option value='0'";
                                if ($paymentTypeId == 0) {
                                    echo " selected='selected'";
                                }
                                echo ">Deposit</option>";
                                echo "<option value='1'";
                                if ($paymentTypeId == 1) {
                                    echo " selected='selected'";
                                }
                                echo ">Balance</option>";
                                echo "<option value='2'";
                                if ($paymentTypeId == 2) {
                                    echo " selected='selected'";
                                }
                                echo ">Full Cost</option>";
                                echo "<option value='3'";
                                if ($paymentTypeId == 3) {
                                    echo " selected='selected'";
                                }
                                echo ">Other</option>";
                                ?>
                            </select>
```

Comment: do you have that Select inside a form ??

Answer (score 0):

you can add one more option

```
echo "<option value='4'";
if ($paymentTypeId == 4) {
       echo " selected='selected'";
}
echo ">Gift Voucher</option>";
```

**UPDATE:**

you can use array without using this messay code like

```
$arr_paymentType = array(
                          -1 => "Please Select",
                           0 => "Deposit",
                           1 => "Balance",
                           2 => "Full Cost",
                           3 => "Other",
                           4 => "Gift Voucher"
                        );
```

Now you can use this array anywhere you want like

```
foreach($arr_paymentType as $key=>$val)
{
    if($key==$paymentTypeId)
    {
           $selected = ' selected="selected" ';
    }  
   echo '<option value="'.$kye.'" '.$selected.' >'.$val.'</option>'
}
```

In above way you can update array value and that will be effective all over there where the array is used.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Tried the first answer. Selecting Other works as it should but selecting Gift Voucher acts as if "Deposit", "Balance" or "Full Cost" were selected on the following page. I'm not that great with PHP so don't want to messing about with the Array option.